# Pandas import error: NumPy was built with baseline optimizations

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Erro the import pandas: **NumPy was built with baseline optimizations:
(SSE SSE2 SSE3 SSSE3 SSE41 POPCNT SSE42) but your machine doesn't support:
(POPCNT).**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HrPVl.png)

Comment: Do edit your question to include the code that you used in a [minimal and reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) manner and [avoid posting code as images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).